# Missing bone rotation when exporting FBX animation to Unity

Tags: animation, unity, .fbx

I've been trying to fix an issue i've been having when exporting a viewport animation to unity,
basically the knife is parented to two bones that controll it, one of the bones controls the knife and the hand that is parented to the knife, the other one only controls the knife, so I use that one for rotation only but when I export it to unity as an FBX the animations from the rotating bone are missing
[image]

[image]

as you can see when it gets exported to unity the knife doesn't rotate and stays in it's original position

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which procedure you followed to export from Rigify to Unity, but if you used some automatic functions, it's possible that the new bone has to be named starting with the DEF- suffix, and has to stay in the bone layer n. 29 (counting from 00 to 31, as Blender internally does), same as all deforming Rigify bones.

[image]